# ES2015 `import` alternative for `require()()`?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, commonjs

Some Node JS libraries (e.g. [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug))  use this pattern with require statements:

```
var debug = require('debug')('http');
```

This is basically a require of a function which is then directly invoked.

**My question**: Is there a similar construct using ES2015 `import` statements?

How would you translate such code if you were converting from commonjs to es2015 syntax?

Comment: Interestingly, I just received a 'Famous Question' badge for this question because it was viewed over 10.000 times... Still it was closed as being a duplicate :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That pattern only works because `require(debug)` returns a value that can be used immediately.

```
var debug = require('debug')('http');
```

`import` is a bit like `if` in the sense that it doesn't resolve as a value.

```
var d = if(a) { b } else { c }; // unexpected token
var debug = import debug from 'debug'; // unexpected token
```

`require` shares semantics with the `?` operator which performs the same function as `if`, but resolves as a value.

```
var d = a ? b : c;
var debug = require('debug');
```

The only option is to split the statement up.

```
import _debug from 'debug';
var debug = _debug('http');
```

Comment: Great comparison thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[There is no such shorthand in ES2015](http://es-discourse.com/t/short-hand-module-syntax/143).

You would just have to split the code into two parts:

```
import _debug from 'debug';
const debug = _debug('http');
```

For which the export would be:

```
export default function { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the link!